Return a Rewrite in Nuxt3 with Nitro server middleware
For a nuxt3 app with the following folder structure:
pages/
├── foo.vue
└── bar.vue
server/
└── middleware/
    └── index.js

How can a rewrite be returned from index.js?
Here is a link to a live example on stackblitz
The code for redirects works just fine, when a user visits /bar they are sent to /foo and the browser url updates accordingly.
export default defineEventHandler(e => {
  if (e.path === '/bar') {
    sendRedirect(e, '/foo')
  }
})

However, what if we wanted to display the content of foo.vue and show /bar in the browser url?
I have tried the proxyRequest(event, target) h3 util function which shows in the network tab that /bar is hit and /foo is returned, but the browser url updates to foo instead of remaining bar
export default defineEventHandler(async e => {
  if (e.path === '/bar') {
    return proxyRequest(e, 'http://localhost:3000/foo')
  }
})

A similar result can be achieved with nitro route rules. This shows bar in the network tab, the preview shows that it did fetch foo, but the url updates in the browser which is not what we want for this use case.
nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    '/bar': { proxy: '/foo' }
  }
})


Why not use redirect? When a user is in the /foo, just redirect it to /bar endpoint

This question is specifically about how to return a rewrite, not why. Netlify offers rewrites by redirecting with a status of 200, next.js offers this, I want to know how this would be done with nuxt3 specifically
